# Imaging with A Fresnel Lens

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, imaging

I am in need of an optics expert on imaging, and in particular a fresnel lens is being used as for an imaging device. From my understanding a condenser lens can be considered equivalent to a plano-convex lens.

Setup:

-A condenser fresnel lens is used, for which both the fresnel and plano conjugates are finite. Meaning these conjugates could be found using the thin lens equation. This only would apply if we wanted the light to focus to a point, which is not what we want.

-Light source projecting a pattern into the fresnel lens.

-Ideally the image produced should be similar to that of 25ft, when in actuality the source has only traveled approximately 3-4'.

-When comparing the pattern at the same distance without the lens, there is a clear difference.

-Image plane at the focal length, for which we should see a formed image.
With initial testing, the size of the image stays the same no matter the light source location. The only thing that actually changes is the amount of the light source that is projected.

A few questions:

-What is the object being imaged? (The object is not the light source but rather it's projection?)

-How does this translate to the traditional thin lens formula?

-The image looks best when the image plane is at the focal length. Why is this this case for imaging a light source?

-Are there any articles/books that would be a good reference for imaging using fresnel lenses?

-Any thoughts or suggestions will be very much appreciated!

For the system setup see diagram below. In our current case, the image plane is on the focal plane.

[image: Diagram of apparatus]

Comment: Fresnel lenses obey the same first order rules of image formation as spherical lenses, but the images tend to be poor quality due the Fresnel facets. Can you draw a picture of what you describe? It is not clear if you are trying to design a system or reverse engineer a current system.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There is a current system I am trying to understand. I will add a diagram shortly.